# Inserting more row into PostgreSQL database table results in all values in one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Noob question. Despite following the official PostgreSQL syntax I cannot insert multiple rows into a table. It always ends up adding all values to the first row.

I first created a table like this:

```
create table "DBSTest".Test (column1 varchar, column2 varchar, column3 varchar);
```

My update statement looks like this:

```
insert into "DBSTest".Test (column1, column2, column3) 
values (
('test1a','test1b'),
('test2a','test2b'),
('test3a','test3b')
);
```

I would expect the table to look like this:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1a | test2a | test3a |
| test1b | test2b | test3b |

Instead it ends up like this:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (test1a,test1b) | (test2a,test2b) | (test3a,test3b) |

Apparently I'm getting something super wrong. I would appreciate any help on this, thanks :)

PS. Edited to get the table format right.

Answer (score 1):

In the VALUES clause of INSERT, each row of data (in your sample each line of data) goes into its own **row** of the table, not its own **column**.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy! I got that the other way round, apparently...

Comment: Yep. I recognized your mistake because I made the same one when learning SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert 3 rows as ('test1a','test1b') in the first column

Try this :

```
insert into Test (column1, column2, column3) 
values 
('test1a','test2a', 'test3b'),
('test1b','test2b', 'test3b');
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy! I got that the other way round, apparently...

Comment: Note that the maximum number of rows in one insert statement is 1000 allowed only.

Answer (score 0):

SQL inserts values by order of rows, not columns, i.e. your query should look like this:

`insert into dbstest (column1, column2, column3) values ('test1a', 'test2a', 'test3a'), ('test1b', 'test2b', 'test3b');`

This then returns the output as you specified:

[image: table]